# How can I create a series of density contours in a row ( i.e. subplots)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I can create a density contour plot with

```
from astropy.table import Table, join
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

# CLEAN Data
RErange = Table.read('../../GAMA_Data/REMassEClassEmeasure.fits')
RErange = RErange[RErange['SurfaceDensityFlag'] == 0]
#RErange = RErange[RErange['SurfaceDensity'] < 50]
RErange = RErange[RErange['AGEDenParFlag'] == 0]
RErange = RErange[RErange['CountInCylFlag'] == 0]
RErange = RErange[RErange['uminusr']> 0.001]

print(RErange.colnames)

yfield = 'uminusr'
xfield ='logmstar'

# set seaborn style
#sns.set_style("white")

df = RErange.to_pandas()
sns.displot(df, x='logmstar', y='uminusr', kind="kde")

plt.show()
```

But how can I create a number of them ( 3 in in a line ) as per subplots?
as seaborn displot does not seem to have an axis facility.

Solution does not have to use seaborn.

Comment: You could use the underlying axes-level function `sns.kdeplot(..., ax=...)` instead.

Comment: Already tried sns.kdeplot but get an error
ValueError: Big-endian buffer not supported on little-endian compiler
hence resorting to displot

Comment: Such error has probably to do with numpy installation (or scipy or astropy). Which seaborn function you are using will not really change that.

Comment: Well astropy is all about astronomy and tables, it reads FITS data which is ALWAYS 'big-endian'. The fact that seaborn displot works fine passing in a data frame. I am sure when I hit the problem originally I googled and advised to use displot. So kdeplot only works for little-ended data ? I tried passing it via a dataframe i.e. sns.kdeplot(df,x='logmstar', y='uminusr', ax = ax1, cmap='Blues') but it did not like it

Comment: Well, `kdeplot` and `displot` use the same internal 100% python code.  The error comes from one of the other libraries.  Note that writing *"it did not like it"* isn't informative, and will not help in finding a solution. Also, note that seaborn recommends explicitly naming the first parameter, as in `sns.kdeplot(data=df, ...)`.  If you really want to use `displot`, you could transform your dataframe to long form and use its `col=` parameter. Your question doesn't contain enough information to know what you'd need exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay resolved by using a Dataframe which resolved the endedness

```
df = RErange.to_pandas()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 16), dpi=200)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
sns.kdeplot(df.logmstar, df.uminusr, ax=ax1, cmap='Blues')
plt.show()
```